# How does the algorithm for an 8-by-8-bit multiplier look like?

Tags: assembly

The teacher gave us an assignment to make a programme that multiplies 2 numbers of 8 bit length. Our micro controller only supports 8-bit registers, therefore the result has to be placed into 2 registers. This is where I am stuck.

To multiply the 2 numbers, I have to shift one of them to the left. And I don't know how I can do this, because when shifting to left, there is just the carry-bit left, where I could paste the number in, but when I have to shift more than just one bit, the carry-bit isn't enough.

Also I don't understand how I would add those numbers. Example:

```
Number1:    Number2:
0000'0111 * 1111'1111
---------------------
            1111'1111
          1'1111'111<  The 1 number on the left would be outside the register.
         11'1111'11<<  The 2 numbers on the left would be outside the register.
         ------------
        110'1111'1001
```

This is the method on the paper. But how do I implement that?

Comment: If you multiply 8b x 8b with the result being 8 bit too, you will have overflow at times (as in your examples). Nothing you can do about that. If you can monitor the carry bit on your architecture, just report overflow in such cases.

Comment: Yes, that would be one way. But we have to make it a multiplier that actually IS capable of multiplying 8x8 and then getting a result that is 16 bit. Which means the result has to be in two registers and I don't know how to calculate with that.

Comment: Can you do it in multiple passes of a 4x4 multiplication? Or translate the number somehow and process it like binary-coded decimal?

ie: you seem to have the same problem as somebody who wants to do 64 bit math on a 32 bit processor. Its doable, just slow.

Comment: I just got the info that we have to do it as follows: 
Number1: Only 1 Register
Number2: 2 Registers, Number2_Low and Number2_High
Now it's alot easier to do it. I think I already have solutions to it. Thanks very much, I have it now.

Comment: Every processor has a left-shift instruction that shifts the carry into bit 0.  Even the lowly 8051, RL vs RLC for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An on-foot way would be as follows. Call the two registers R_h and R_l, and initialize to 0. Create a mask  M_l := 0x01. Call the multiplicand register x, multiplier register y. You also will use a register R_t.. Then, in pseudo code:

(0) set i = 0, j =8

(1) iterate 8 times (i)

(2) if (and x, M_l) == 0, go to (8)

(3)(a) sll y, i, and save in R_t

(3)(b) add R_l, R_t, and save in R_l

(4) if carry bit not set, go to (6)

(5) add R_h, 1

(6) srl y, j, and store in R_t. This is what you push into R_h from just adjusting the position (leave value in y as is).

(7) add R_h, R_t, and store in R_h (your interim result is now correct).

(8) i++, j--

(9) sll M_l, 1

(10) jmp (1)

I could easily have an off-by-one error; but in principle, this should work. There is probably a standard algorithm for this, but that's what came to mind.

Comment: This is for the original question, both x and y 8 bit; result 16 bits by having a res_h and res_l.

Comment: It's a little bit hard for me to understand but I'll try it. In (3), what is "sll" ?

Comment: Shift left logical, by the number of bits i. It's implemented in all languages I know. Just look at it visually: you need some of the bits to add 'as if there is no overflow' - if there is, add one more to the higher register ("to its left") (and to see which to add in this round, you need to sll); and, in each iteration, the i right-most bits of the multiplier need to be added to the higher register (first time: 0; next time: highest; then two highest, etc), and srl does that.  THe algorithm only describes what you wrote down in your example.

Comment: You can read more about sll/rll [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift). Just ignore the 'logical' (there's also an arithmetic shift type, but most of the times (eg, called sla), you'll see the 'l' type.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that when you add X to (X << n), the n last bits of the sum do not change:

Thus, when ever you need to add

```
  |ABCDEFGH
 A|BCDEFGH0  <-- the value shifted by 1, A doesn't fit in the 8-bit registers
 ----------
 c|xxxxxxxH  <-- you have the last bit
```

Convert this to:

```
      |0ABCDEFG (H) is shifted out, that's one more correct bit of the result
      |ABCDEFGH
     ----------
 (C) + xxxxxxxx  <-- you get 8 bit of result + Carry
```

Repeating this 8 times will lead in 8 least significant bits shifted out, and the 8 most significant bit of the result stored in the accumulator. In each round, the carry will actually replace the '0' in the upper row:

```
     Partial sum = (c) | xxxxxxxX

     Shift PS >> 1 -->  Partial sum = cxxxxxxx | C <= X
```

This of course relies on the architecture being implementing wisely (that there exists a rotate right through carry instruction).

Another options include splitting the operands to sections, which can be multiplied natively without overflow. Given a "processor" that can hold any value 0<= x<= 100, you can multiply 2 digit numbers or even larger:

```
    78 * 65 == 7*6 (*10^2) + 7*5 * (10^1) + 8*6 * (10^1) + 8*5
```

An option to multiply (small) numbers in micro-controller include the x^2 table:

```
a*b = ((a+b)^2 - (a-b)^2) / 4 =
      ((a+b / 2)) ^ 2 - ((a-b)/2)^2 + A,
      where A an adjustment term just too difficult to remember, but possible
      to derive if needed.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it somehow, and it works. I'm really sorry, that I couldn't use your answers, I'm still a newbie and don't understand a lot of the stuff you were writing about.

My solution:

```
Main:   

IN      Number1, SWITCH
IN      Number2_L, SWITCH2
CLR     Number2_H
CLR     Product_L
CLR     Product_H
Loop:   TST     Number1  ; Number1 > 0 ?
        BREQ    JEnd     ; If not, jump to JEnd
        LSR     Number1  ; Logical Shift Right to Carry
        BRCC    JNoC     ; If Carry not set, then jump to JNoC
        ADD     Product_L, Number2_L
        ADC     Product_H, Number2_H
JNoC:   LSL     Number2_L   ;Logical Shift Left to Carry
        ROL     Number2_H   ;Rotate Left through/from Carry
        RJMP    Loop        
JEnd:   OUT     LED, Product_L
        OUT     LED2, Product_H
        RJMP    Main      ; Infinite loop
```

Note:

ADD is Rd <- Rd + Rr

ADC is Rd <- Rd + Rr + C